# Android: Editing audio files

Tags: android, audio, edit

I'm trying to write an android app that takes a video or audio file and edits the audio. I know you can learn PCM audio which will teach you what you need to know, but I was wondering if Google has some built in function with Android?

I know Android has many different things built into Android that help with bitmaps and queres and stuff, but I was curious if they had anything that could help me edit audio files in Android.

Do the people who make the "autotune" apps have some packages they share that can aid and help in the Android development community?

I know someone already asked a question about editing audio files with regular programming, but I wanted to know if there was something already in Android made for me.

I've viewed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366187/getting-started-with-programmatic-audio/366246#366246) which gave me a little bit of an idea of PCM audio.

Thanks in advance!!

I'm new to android and am trying to get my feet wet with some app ideas I have. If anybody has some resources that are really useful to learn android, please let me know. I've been reading Google's soruces on their website, there isn't a whole lot on there. Also, tried youtube which is very skim.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html is the Android API for handling audio at the lowest level, it is a little heavy. But one such method:  `public int attachAuxEffect (int effectId)`
"Attaches an auxiliary effect to the audio track" might pertain to what you want to accomplish.