# making an android project using introjucer

Tags: android, juce

I would like to edit an audio file. As java doesn't support voice libraries(according to my knowledge), I would like to use `juce` library for this.
From some resources found in google, I came to know that we can do it using `introjucer`..
but i couldn't find proper tutorials for making `android` projects using `introjucer`. Can anyone help me out with this? Please correct me if i've misinterpreted any concept.

Answer (score 1):

1. Best Useful library for audio editing is ringdroid: https://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/
2. Android Audio reference.
   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html is the Android API for handling audio at the lowest level.
3. Second check out this -> [Getting started with programmatic audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366187/getting-started-with-programmatic-audio/366246#366246)

If you dont want to use ringdroid.

4. Juce Hello world Tutorial : http://jucevst.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/hello-world-with-juce-actually-making-something/
5. Juce Beginner Tutorial: http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=10953#p61988