# Audio Units Development (OS X)

Tags: macos, audio, core-audio

I'm quite new to Core Audio development. I did many google searches but so far I couldn't come up with something useful for bootstrapping the process.I looked through the Apple Audio Unit Guide but it is outdated and uses Core Audio SDK which I even cant find for downloading. Is there any useful resources with audio Unit development apart from the horrible Apple guide?

Comment: Why do you have an iOS key on your question if this is for OS X? (Can't help with your question - sorry.)

Comment: Core Audio and Audio Units are now supported in both iOS and OSX.

Comment: This will be your new Bible: http://www.amazon.com/Learning-Core-Audio-Hands-On-Programming/dp/0321636848

Comment: @rocky I actually read majority of the book, the problem with the book is that it scratched only the surface of audio units and didn't provided any useful examples other than a few 'configuration' examples and there was no references for further information.

Comment: Well what exactly are you trying to accomplish? I feel that the book has a good beginning overview of Audio Units (better than any Apple provides) and equips the reader with the tools to build more complicated programs.

Comment: In terms of functionality something similar to 'Boom 2' basically an equalizer along with some audio effects.

Answer (score 2):

I feel that this book has a good beginning overview of Audio Units (better than any Apple provides) and equips the reader with the tools to build more complicated programs.

[http://www.amazon.com/Learning-Core-Audio-Hands-On-Programming/dp/0321636848](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321636848)

Chapter 7 in the book has an example of adding a reverb effect. So you can use that to guide you on whatever audio effects you want to add. As for the equalizer functions, there are audio units for it, also located in Chapter 7. If none of these accomplish what you want, you can always intercept the PCM audio data in the callback and manipulate the raw data. Though that does require you to know some DSP, which is too advanced for me.

Here are some useful posts I found:

http://www.deluge.co/?q=content/coreaudio-iphone-creating-graphic-equalizer

http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt

[Getting started with programmatic audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366187/getting-started-with-programmatic-audio)

Answer (score 1):

Audio Unit tutorials and the Learning Core Audio book are mostly about using the Core Audio API.  If you want to know more about how to actually process the audio data inside an Audio Unit for some effect, the subject in which you may really be interested is Digital Signal Processing (DSP).  It's a large non-trivial subject area.  There are many entire university-level textbooks on the subject, as well as a specialty dsp.stackexchange site.  For starters, try [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/books-that-explain-dsp-well-to-those-not-directly-in-engineering/2208#2208) or [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/22264/book-recommendations-on-dsp-statistical-sp-and-signal-detection).